# Install sharepoint 2010 with existing databases

Tags: 2010

I have a SP2010 server farm but need to reinstall sp as I never set a sql alias.

If I do this, how do I restore the original farm/central admin and admin content db's?

I have the above DB's, web app db's, and user profile db's.

Also, I installed sharepoint 2010 sp1 + june cu. Does the uninstall wipe out the june cu?

Answer (score 1):

I think its a bit extreme looking to do a reinstall, just setup the SQL alias as you intend to do and you should be able to get away with a renameserver operation

stsadm -o renameserver -oldservername "OLD_SQL_INSTANCE" -newservername "SQL_ALIASNAME"

Further info here
http://blog.bugrapostaci.com/2011/07/25/how-to-rename-sharepoint-database-server/